# How to find references in workspace (ctrl+shift+g) in Eclipse PHP?

Tags: php, eclipse, search, reference, workspace

I'm using Eclipse PDT, and I have opened my project in PHP, the auto-complete works, the type searching works, but what doesn't work is if I click the name of the function and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> it doesn't return other references to that function in the workspace.

I'm familiar with Java + Eclipse, and doing this in Java brings up a search of all calls to that function in the workspace.  I'm brand new to PHP, so is there something wrong? Does PHP not "reference" things like in Java?

(Note: I did set up the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> key binding to Find references in workspace)

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a dynamic scripting language. This also means it's very hard to determine the types of the elements in the code, and in some cases, impossible in 'design-time'. This is one of the main reasons products like PDT and Aptana Studio highly rely on the PHPDoc to provide accurate code assist and type-binding.

It's very different from Java by nature, so finding references, refactoring, and other advanced features you are familiar with in the Java Plugin, are missing in the PDT.

Some of those do exist in other products. For example - refactoring in Zend Studio, and 'code exploration' in nWire for PHP. Those product cost money...

Hope that helps.